# message display/block on button click

Tags: javascript, css

I have kept notification button in my header.
When user click `Get notified` then it should replace by message `Notified successfully`

CODEPEN: [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/flukL)

**HTML**

```
<li style="display:none" id="l1"><a href="#about">Notified soccessfully ..</a>
</li>
<li><a style="display:block" id="l2" href="#about">Email</a>
</li>
<li>
<div id="input-collection" class="input-group input-group-lg left-input-group">
```

**JS**

```
function notify()
{
  alert("hi");
  document.getElementById("l2").dispaly='none';
  document.getElementById("input-collection").dispaly='none';
  document.getElementById("l1").dispaly='block';
}
```

In codepen, donno what is the issue with my code.

Comment: Change dispaly to display and apply it to its style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IT should be `display` not `dispaly` and you should provide `.style`

```
function notify()
{
    alert("hi");
    document.getElementById("l2").style.display='none'; // Changed
    document.getElementById("input-collection").style.display='none'; // Changed
    document.getElementById("l1").style.display='block'; // Changed
}
```

[**Code Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLuij)

Comment: thanks, still probelm persist. On button click 'notification box' should be replaced by message

Comment: @user3121782 I can see it's replaces email with the messesge! What else you require? Can you elaborate?

Comment: notification box should be disappeared. only `notified successfully` message should apear

Comment: @user3121782 [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLuij) is the solution Is that you want? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44240/discussion-between-user3121782-and-dhaval-marthak)